# How to get the same push output using a date range in Git?

Tags: git

I like how `git` shows how much code I pushed to the server `[1]` , is there a way to get that input date ranges or commits?

```
[1]: 6 files changed, 575 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push origin your_branch --verbose
```

This should give you a hash range in the output. Now you can do:

```
git log sha1A..sha1B
```

If you want to experiment with this first add `--dry-run` to the push - the push won't actually happen.

But before you push, you can also try:

```
git log origin/your_branch..your_branch
```

This will show you the commits you will push. If your_branch is already checked out, you can just issue:

```
git log origin/your_branch..
```

This will implicitly match the range to HEAD which is your branch.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The primary ways to get this kind of information are the `--shortstat`, `--stat` and `--numstat` options which can be passed to the diffcore machinery, e.g. through `git-diff` and `git-log`.

In your case, it sounds like you want the `--shortstat` option, which only gives the summary line, not the pretty information for each file like you see after a pull given by `--stat`. The last one, `--numstat`, gives the same file-by-file information in a more machine-readable format.

To apply this to a commit range, just use `git diff --shortstat A B`, where `A` and `B` are the commits you want to compare.

To get that same information for each individual commit in the range, instead of all lumped together, use `git log --shortstat A..B`.

If you want to do this by date, you have a couple options:

- Specify a single commit using the form `<branch>@{<date>}`. Be aware, though, that this gives the position of that branch on that given date. This is fine if it's a long-lived local branch, but if it didn't exist yet on that date, or it's a remote branch that moves in big leaps when you fetch, that might not be what you want.
- Use the `--since` and `--until` options for `git log`. This does mean that you'll have to use two steps if you want the overall summary - one to figure out the commits on each end of the range, and one to actually do the diff.

For more information on how to specify commits see [`man gitrevisions`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).